# Evaluate several bools, break on first true c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, if-statement

All, quick and easy one here...

I'm writing an Evaluate function that runs through a bunch of other bool functions. Right now, I'm basically doing an if, else if loop (seen below). Any suggestions on another way of doing this???  I'm assuming I could do this with a switch but have never used them before like this.

```
int i = 78;

if (isPrime(i))
{
     cout <<"is prime" << endl;
     return;
}

else if (ismultipleOf23(i))
{
    cout <<"is a multiple of 23" << endl;
    return;
}

else if (isEven(i))
{
    cout <<"is Even" << endl;
    return;
}

else if (isOdd(i))
{
    cout <<"is Odd" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it. No, you cannot conveniently use `switch` here. `&&` and `||` are sometimes good for concision but if you are going to have side-effects, it would be poor style to use them.

Comment: 23 is a prime and prime numbers are a subset of odd numbers. A multiple of 23 could be even or odd. If/else doesn't really work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a switch because the labels have to be constant.

What you are doing is the correct way.

Comment: What if they were C++11 constexpr?

Comment: @Pubby8, don't know C++11, can't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the returns and you don't need to check for odd because if it is not even, it has to be odd.

```
int i = 78;

if (isPrime(i))
{
   cout <<"is prime" << endl;
}
else if (ismultipleOf23(i))
{
  cout <<"is a multiple of 23" << endl;
}
else if (isEven(i))
{
  cout <<"is Even" << endl;
}
else
{
  cout <<"is Odd" << endl;
}
return;  // This is also optional
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not worth it for so few tests, but if you had many tests you could put them in a  list and iterate over them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct TEST {
    bool (*func)(int);
    string msg;
};

bool isMult23(int i) { return i % 23 == 0; }
bool isEven(int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }
bool isOdd(int i) { return !isEven(i); }
bool isOther(int i) { return true; } // sentinel, always true

TEST test[] = {
    isMult23,"is multiple of 23",
    isEven,"is even",
    isOdd,"is odd",
    isOther,"is something else"
};

string eval(int value)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(!test[i].func(value))
        i++;
    return test[i].msg;
}

int main()
{
    cout << eval(46) << endl;
    cout << eval(78) << endl;
    cout << eval(81) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
is multiple of 23
is even
is odd
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do some crazy stuff with templates, lambdas, and such that would allow you to easily add new tests and to loop through the set of tests, executing a lambda on success and returning...

But that would be overkill and would require a somewhat standard-compliant compiler (since C++11 is now the standard, I'm comfortable with that statement).